# PHP special chars to html entity codes

Tags: php, special-characters, html-entities, array-map

I am trying to convert the special chars in my array to html entity codes:

this is my helper array:

```
'specialChars' => [
    '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+',
    ',', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\',
    ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '§', '©', '¶'
]
```

And this is the function:

```
    public static function convert($specialChars = [])
    {
        $htmlEntityArray = [];

        if(count($specialChars) == 0)
        {
            $specialChars = Config::get('constants.specialChars'); // gets the special char from the helper array
        }

        foreach ($specialChars as $key => $value)
        {
            $htmlEntityArray = array_map("htmlentities", $specialChars);
        }

        return $htmlEntityArray;
    }
```

But that only returns me this array, it convert some successfully and some not:

```
array:32 [▼
  0 => "!"
  1 => "&quot;"
  2 => "#"
  3 => "$"
  4 => "%"
  5 => "&amp;"
  6 => "'"
  7 => "("
  8 => ")"
  9 => "*"
  10 => "+"
  11 => ","
  12 => "/"
  13 => ":"
  14 => ";"
  15 => "&lt;"
  16 => "="
  17 => "&gt;"
  18 => "?"
  19 => "@"
  20 => "["
  21 => "\"
  22 => "]"
  23 => "^"
  24 => "_"
  25 => "`"
  26 => "{"
  27 => "|"
  28 => "}"
  29 => "&sect;"
  30 => "&copy;"
  31 => "&para;"
]
```

Comment: why not just use php's [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) functions, which are made to do this

Comment: re-inventing the wheel i see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `ENT_QUOTES` and `ENT_HTML5` [flags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#refsect1-function.htmlentities-parameters).

```
$specialChars = [
    '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+',
    ',', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\',
    ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '§', '©', '¶'
];

var_export(array_map(function ($str) { return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5); }, $specialChars));
```

This returns:

```
array (
    0 => '&excl;',
    1 => '&quot;',
    2 => '&num;',
    3 => '&dollar;',
    4 => '&percnt;',
    5 => '&amp;',
    6 => '&apos;',
    7 => '&lpar;',
    8 => '&rpar;',
    9 => '&ast;',
    10 => '&plus;',
    11 => '&comma;',
    12 => '&sol;',
    13 => '&colon;',
    14 => '&semi;',
    15 => '&lt;',
    16 => '&equals;',
    17 => '&gt;',
    18 => '&quest;',
    19 => '&commat;',
    20 => '&lbrack;',
    21 => '&bsol;',
    22 => '&rsqb;',
    23 => '&Hat;',
    24 => '&lowbar;',
    25 => '&grave;',
    26 => '&lbrace;',
    27 => '&vert;',
    28 => '&rcub;',
    29 => '&sect;',
    30 => '&copy;',
    31 => '&para;',
)
```

Comment: How would I need to edit the function to make something like this avaible:

`Menu::convert('my name?');`

And to get as an output

`my name&quest;`

Comment: Don't use a method, just call `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5)` @utdev. I suppose you could use a method if this was called in lots of places though.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the second parameter "flag" of htmlentities like this

```
$htmlEntityArray = array_map(function($char) {
  return htmlentities($char, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
}, $specialChars);
```

Comment: ENT_HTML5 did not show all I need ENT_QUOTES aswell

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I didn't check the entity list, thus didn't notice that all characters have translations available. I'm leaving the answer though in case it can help others with a different list of characters.*

---

From [docs](http://php.net/htmlentities) (emphasis mine):

> all characters **which have HTML character entity equivalents** are translated into these entities.
>
> See Also
>
> - [get_html_translation_table()](http://php.net/get_html_translation_table) - Returns the translation table used by htmlspecialchars and htmlentities

In other situations you could have a better result with [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding) using `HTML-ENTITIES` as target encoding. The problem is that there isn't an obvious pattern in your entities (most of them are basic US-ASCII characters that do not have any special meaning in HTML, thus don't need to be converted to HTML entities for any of the usual reasons). So you're left two options:

- Generate a numeric entity with the help of e.g. [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) and [pack()](http://php.net/pack).
- Hard-code the complete entity list and get replacements done with [strtr()](http://php.net/strtr).